# Why is my 3rd box not aligned with the first two?

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/KpLyn

I am simply trying to horizontally align 3 boxes inside a parent div.  The third one is appearing far below the first two.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
.parentbox{
  width:1120px;
  padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  align: center;
  height: auto;
}
.box1 {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;

}
.box2 {
  float: middle;
  width: 23%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;

}
.box4 {
  float: right;
  width: 23%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;

}


<div class="parentbox">
  <div align=center>
    <div class="box1">hello</div>
    <div class="box2">hi</div>
    <div class="box4">hgi</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of flaws with your CSS code but the biggest one causing the display issue is:

```
.box2 {
   float: middle;
```

}

There is no `float: middle;` property. You need to either set them all to `float:left;` (or `float:right;`) or use an entirely different approach. (like using `display: table-cell;`)

Comment: Agreed. display:inline-block; (and probably vertical-align:top; for safety) could have saved the OP some grief, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I simplified your code, just using a unique class for the three divs, and display them `inline-block`, please see below:

```css
.parentbox {
  width: 1120px;
  padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  align: center;
  height: auto;
}
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  /* vertical-align:top;  you might need this property */
  width: 23%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentbox">
  <div align=center>
    <div class="box">hello</div>
    <div class="box">hi</div>
    <div class="box">hgi</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rishabh66/kLfb2wet/ .

Add `float: left;` to all divs 
to make horizontally align boxes inside parent div.